# What counts as proof of car ownership in Alberta?

Tags: registration

I am importing a vehicle from Alberta to Pennsylvania, and Pennsylvania wants a "car title."  I owned 3 cars in Canada and never had a "car title." My Alberta dealership told me that the "registration" is the same thing as the title. Can anybody confirm what counts as proof of ownership in Alberta?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I can't speak for Alberta, but usually the registration document is not proof of ownership, it is proof of possession.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Alberta, the bill of sale (or signed lease) is considered to be the proof of ownership. This is what the Registry agent requires before they can register the car.

[Alberta Registries](https://www.alberta.ca/register-vehicle.aspx)

There are no such thing as a title in Alberta. As to how you'd explain and prove this to the Pennsylvania DOT is a good question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have ever had a title if you were making payments on the vehicle. At least here in the States, if you are making payments, the financial institution you are making payments to is considered the "lienholder" on the vehicle and holds the title as collateral to show proof *they own the car* until you are through making payments on it.

If you are still making payments on your car and have a current registration, you'd need to provide your banking institution as the lienholder and you should be good to go. I've never done this, so there may be more to it then that. You should talk directly to the PA Department of Motor Vehicles (DMV) to see what they require. Not every state is going to be exactly the same.

Comment: Not related to vehicle title but clearly related to importing a car from overseas into the US: the OP will also need to address the US's federal requirements for compliance with DOT (physical safety and equipment) and EPA (emissions) regulations.

Comment: @DavidRemembersMonica - You are most spot on with that. Luckily for the OP, I'm pretty sure Canada's emissions and safety standards are very close to what they are here in the US. However, the OP will need to still deal with them.

Comment: @Paulster2 At least in the past, that car x was built to the same standards as car y was not sufficient — the feds required the manufacturer to certify that the car in question met the US requirements...and manufacturers resolutely refused to do that in order to protect their US dealer networks. [The earlier answer](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/14065/buy-a-new-volvo-in-canada-and-import-into-us/14071#14071) addresses the issue. The OP here will need to find out what the law is now, and may have to adjust their plans.

Comment: @DavidRemembersMonica - That's great information. Thanks for sharing the link.